# Receive data from other apps in react-native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

How do I receive simple data from other apps on android and iOS? For example, URLs from browsers and RSS-aggregators.
Is there some libraries or so?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you wanting to fetch data from an api?

Comment: no, i want to receive data from any apps, which have sharing functionality. On android such apps have a button, something like "Share...". If i click this button, it will open special android's popup. This popup contains all the apps, which are able to receive simple data - all social network apps, evernote, pocket, dropbox, googleDrive, email-clients etc...

Comment: @NaderDabit, i want to add my app into iOS sharing actionSheet: http://www.techotopia.com/images/6/6b/Ios_7_social_share.png

Comment: [react-native-share-extension](https://github.com/alinz/react-native-share-extension) should provide you with a good starting point as you're looking for share activity for your ios application

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use app links http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html#content.
For more advanced android intents, you would have to implement that as a native module.

Comment: Thank you, how do i add my app into iOS sharing actionsheet? http://www.techotopia.com/images/6/6b/Ios_7_social_share.png